# iisnode gives 'Bad Request' for post method

Tags: node.js, express, iis, iisnode

I have developed nodejs express app. It is working fine when running on node server. But after hosting on iis server it always gives 'Bad Request' as response.
Get calls are working fine.

following is my web.conf file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>         
      <handlers>
           <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
     </handlers>
      <rewrite>
           <rules>

                <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">                    
                    <match url="^server.js\/debug[\/]?" />
                </rule>

                <rule name="StaticContent">
                     <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
                </rule>

                <rule name="DynamicContent">
                     <conditions>
                          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
                     </conditions>
                     <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
                </rule>

           </rules>
      </rewrite>

      <iisnode     
      nodeProcessCommandLine="C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"
      nodeProcessCountPerApplication="1"
      maxConcurrentRequestsPerProcess="1024"
      maxNamedPipeConnectionRetry="100"
      namedPipeConnectionRetryDelay="250"      
      maxNamedPipeConnectionPoolSize="512"
      maxNamedPipePooledConnectionAge="30000"
      asyncCompletionThreadCount="0"
      initialRequestBufferSize="4096"
      maxRequestBufferSize="65536"
      watchedFiles="*.js;iisnode.yml"
      uncFileChangesPollingInterval="5000"      
      gracefulShutdownTimeout="60000"
      loggingEnabled="false"
      logDirectory="iisnode"
      debuggingEnabled="true"
      debugHeaderEnabled="false"
      debuggerPortRange="5058-6058"
      debuggerPathSegment="debug"
      maxLogFileSizeInKB="128"
      maxTotalLogFileSizeInKB="1024"
      maxLogFiles="20"
      devErrorsEnabled="true"
      flushResponse="false"      
      enableXFF="false"
      promoteServerVars=""
      configOverrides="iisnode.yml"

     />
     <modules>
       <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
    </modules>
   </system.webServer>
 </configuration>
```

server.js file as follows

```
'use strict';

// Module dependencies.
var express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    methodOverride = require('method-override'),
    morgan = require('morgan'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = module.exports = exports.app = express();

app.locals.siteName = "IOS IBE";

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});

app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));


// Start server
var port = process.env.PORT;
app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('DP Admin server listening on port %d in %s mode', port, app.get('env'));
});
```

Comment: Can  you resolve this problem? I have same problem hosting in VM with IIS

Comment: @CampDev Please check the answer. It works for me.

Answer (score 3):

I could fixed this issue by adding

```
<system.webServer>
   <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" /> 
</system.webServer>
```

to web.config .

Hope this will help to any one else.